# sum values in dictionary - python 3

Tags: python, dictionary, sum

Does anyone know why this simple code isn't working ?
using IDEone compiler by the way 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4THj.png)

Comment: If the code is simple, then inline the code in the post.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Post code, not pictures of code.  Define not working.  If there is an error, include that and the full traceback in your question. 
 What output do you expect? What output did you get?

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post your code in your question so it's more accessible for answerers!

The problem here is `{dict}.values()` returns a list of lists which `sum()` doesn't work on. You can loop over the lists and sum those together. I wrote the following in ipython:

```
In [1]: test = {'A':[1,2,3],'B':[1,2,3],'C':[1,2,3]}

In [2]: test.values()
Out[2]: dict_values([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])

In [3]: total = 0

In [4]: for val in test.values():
   ...:     total += sum(val)
   ...:

In [5]: total
Out[5]: 18
```